# Open the particular page on click the pushwoosh notification

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

I am using the cordova based pushwoosh plugin in my ionic app. It is used for getting push notification. When I click the push notification it is open the app in home.html view but I want to some other page like contact.html. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom data feature in Pushwoosh.

1. [Custom Data in Pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/custom-data/)
2. [Using Custom Data](https://www.pushwoosh.com/using-custom-data/)

Custom data feature would do the trick. It allows to send a "key":"value" pair (please see screenshot attached) for application to process when user taps on the notification.[image]

For instance, in our Android demo application (you can download it in Google Play), you can change the background color with the following custom data: { "r" : "0 - 255", "g" : "0 - 255", "b" : "0 - 255" }

Ref: https://community.pushwoosh.com/questions/751/open-a-page-inside-the-app-after-receiving-app-phonegap

Comment: Already I seen your answer on pushwoosh site. Can you explain the programmatically that means demo code?

Comment: Can you provide a tutorial or a sample ?